# Using application in html with asp

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm working on a website with ASP and I'm using this code to transfer variables from page to another:

```
Application["source"] = "testpage"
```

This is used in .cs file, how can I use 'Application' and set a value in 'source' from html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use the [Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525360(v=vs.90).aspx) from the source code of an HTML files instead of the code-behind (the .cs file)?  The short answer is that you can't.

The Application object is one of the [built-in objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524716(v=vs.90).aspx) of ASP and can only be manipulated with code that runs on the server.  The HTML file is rendered on the client (the web browser).

You could show the contents in the browser by using code like the following in the .cs file:

```
Response.Write(Application["source"].toString());
```

This should print "testpage" in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in controller:

```
ViewData["source"] = "testpage"
```

And this in View:

```
<label>@ViewData["source"]</label>
```

Also, you can use `ViewBag.Source` instead of `ViewData["source"]` both in Controller in View